# Lost Realm Evo 2 monsters dropping the same loot every time

Tags: castle-clash

For the past two weeks or so, I sometimes encounter Evo 2 monsters in the Lost Realm:

[image]

I always win and expected a good loot (e.g. Gold Key, Mythic crests, etc.) however they **always** drop only Crest Box, either ordinary or rare, which is really weird.

This happened at least 10 times, so can't be just coincidence of random loot.

What's going on? Is this on purpose? In such case, it's not worth to spend 18 steps on such battles.

Comment: Coincidence I think... I am getting whole sort of rewards. Any change in that matter after latest upgrade?

Comment: @user3328469 no change, and it's over 30 encounters already. (They become more and more frequent.)